3 sets of wires coming from ceiling that I need to connect 2 wire light fixture to
[![

[

]4]4My bathroom ceiling light box has 3 sets of black and white wires coming from it and I can't remember how they were wired together when I took the old fixture out.  I know there were black and white wires tied together but in which order I don't know.  The light is only controlled by one switch, but I figured out that one of these wires also controls the light switch for my over the sink light, the outlet still works for the over the sink light but the switch doesn't.  The picture of the light switch plate took off is the switch that controls the over head light, the picture with the outlet is the switch that controls the over the sink light

Please post photos

ceiling light box only needs two wires to work, using the meter find out which one is permanently hot and which one is switched hot

How is the switch wired up? Post pictures of that as well.
